# T-SQL How to get rows for each 5 minutes from the minutes set

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this kind of data in the table.

What I need to get somehow not all rows but rows with interval of 5 minutes
in order to reduce their quantity.

Is it possible to do in simple way with T-SQL?

```
ID    AtTime                  Speed  Label 
------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
217   2017-06-06 08:01:01.000   0    Lat: 54.3956 Lon: 86.79349
217   2017-06-06 08:01:23.000   0    Lat: 54.3956 Lon: 86.7935
221   2017-06-06 08:04:20.000   0    Lat: 54.39548 Lon: 86.79372
217   2017-06-06 08:06:24.000   0    Lat: 54.39559 Lon: 86.79347
221   2017-06-06 08:09:21.000   0    Lat: 54.39548 Lon: 86.79372
217   2017-06-06 08:11:25.000   0    Lat: 54.3956 Lon: 86.79346
221   2017-06-06 08:12:21.000   0    Lat: 54.39526 Lon: 86.79405
221   2017-06-06 08:12:30.000   0    Lat: 54.39507 Lon: 86.79451
221   2017-06-06 08:12:36.000   14,4    Lat: 54.39503 Lon: 86.79493
221   2017-06-06 08:12:47.000   10,8    Lat: 54.39518 Lon: 86.79536
221   2017-06-06 08:12:56.000   7,2  Lat: 54.39527 Lon: 86.79578
221   2017-06-06 08:13:06.000   7,2  Lat: 54.39529 Lon: 86.79622
221   2017-06-06 08:14:10.000   0    Lat: 54.39545 Lon: 86.79621
```

Comment: From the data you provided: it is not exactly 5 min interval. Can we say the interval should be >= 5 min?

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk Yes, it could be

Comment: So, *what* should the content of those rows be? And are we expected to "fill in" rows for which no row covers a particular time interval?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Well.. Insted of 10000 rows we need to see just some of them it is like 1 row within each 5 minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this meets your needs - we first create a CTE that identifies each of the five minute blocks within your data set. We then use a second CTE to pick the earliest row within each block. I wasn't sure whether `ID` should be used as a second partitioning criterion but I've marked where that could be added:

```
declare @t table (ID int not null, AtTime datetime not null, Speed decimal(9,4)  not null,
                  Label varchar(29) not null)
insert into @t(ID,AtTime,Speed,Label) values
(217,'2017-06-06T08:01:01.000',0   ,'Lat: 54.3956 Lon: 86.79349 '),
(217,'2017-06-06T08:01:23.000',0   ,'Lat: 54.3956 Lon: 86.7935  '),
(221,'2017-06-06T08:04:20.000',0   ,'Lat: 54.39548 Lon: 86.79372'),
(217,'2017-06-06T08:06:24.000',0   ,'Lat: 54.39559 Lon: 86.79347'),
(221,'2017-06-06T08:09:21.000',0   ,'Lat: 54.39548 Lon: 86.79372'),
(217,'2017-06-06T08:11:25.000',0   ,'Lat: 54.3956 Lon: 86.79346 '),
(221,'2017-06-06T08:12:21.000',0   ,'Lat: 54.39526 Lon: 86.79405'),
(221,'2017-06-06T08:12:30.000',0   ,'Lat: 54.39507 Lon: 86.79451'),
(221,'2017-06-06T08:12:36.000',14.4,'Lat: 54.39503 Lon: 86.79493'),
(221,'2017-06-06T08:12:47.000',10.8,'Lat: 54.39518 Lon: 86.79536'),
(221,'2017-06-06T08:12:56.000',7.2 ,'Lat: 54.39527 Lon: 86.79578'),
(221,'2017-06-06T08:13:06.000',7.2 ,'Lat: 54.39529 Lon: 86.79622'),
(221,'2017-06-06T08:14:10.000',0   ,'Lat: 54.39545 Lon: 86.79621')

;With Times as (
    select distinct u.StartBlock,DATEADD(minute,5,u.StartBlock) as EndBlock
    from @t
        cross apply
        (select DATEADD(minute,((DATEDIFF(minute,0,AtTime)/5)*5),0) as StartBlock) u
), Ordered as (
    select
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StartBlock /* And ID? */ ORDER BY AtTime) as rn
    from
        @t t
            inner join
        Times tm
            on
                tm.StartBlock <= t.AtTime and
                t.AtTime < tm.EndBlock
)
select *
from Ordered
where rn = 1
```

Result:

```
ID          AtTime                  Speed   Label                         StartBlock              EndBlock                rn
----------- ----------------------- ------- ----------------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- --
217         2017-06-06 08:01:01.000 0.0000  Lat: 54.3956 Lon: 86.79349    2017-06-06 08:00:00.000 2017-06-06 08:05:00.000 1
217         2017-06-06 08:06:24.000 0.0000  Lat: 54.39559 Lon: 86.79347   2017-06-06 08:05:00.000 2017-06-06 08:10:00.000 1
217         2017-06-06 08:11:25.000 0.0000  Lat: 54.3956 Lon: 86.79346    2017-06-06 08:10:00.000 2017-06-06 08:15:00.000 1
```

Note that this doesn't guarantee that all rows are *at least* 5 minutes apart. In pathological cases you may have two rows which are in fact only instants apart (e.g. if a particular 5 minute interval only has a single row and it's at the last possible instant in that interval, and the next interval has a row which occurs at exactly the start point). For normal distributions of data though, the data should *on average* by five minutes apart.